# How to print characters after word boundary

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following line of code, it is used to break a long sentence into pieces with specified character length, and can only break on word boundaries:

```
print "$_\n" for grep substr($_, 0, 80), /(.{1,80}\b)/g;
```

If it applies to the following line:

> So-called smartguns have been in the works for years but haven’t
>   gotten much traction.

It will not print the '.' after word traction. What can I do to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goal for regex, span 80 or fewer characters, and end on a non space.  It should be followed by either a space or end of string, and then we should gobble any following spaces so that the following line starts on a character.   A web provided description can be found [here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28.%7B1,80%7D%29%28?%3C=%5CS%29%28?=%5Cs%7C%24%29%5Cs%2a).

```
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp(my $line = $_);

    print "$_\n" for $line =~ /(.{1,80})(?<=\S)(?=\s|$)\s*/g;
}

__DATA__
So-called smartguns have been in the works for years but haven't gotten much traction.
```

Can also just rely on [cpan Text::Wrap](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Text%3a%3aWrap)

Comment: thank you for your solution, it works perfectly. I am new to Perl and regex, could you please explain the regex you provided a little?

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide a basic description of the regex.  For a detailed analysis of a regex, just google "[describe a regular expression](https://www.google.com/#q=describe+a+regular+expression)" and the first result is often a resource for providing a detailed parsing of any regex.

Answer (score 1):

`'.'` at the end of the line does not match your regular expression, so it doesn't get returned by the expression `/(.{1,80}\b)/g`.

It seems to me what you're *really* trying to do is break up lines on spaces. With your existing regex you could conceivably split a contraction (`haven\n't`, for example) or any other number of corner cases you haven't considered.

Maybe

```
/(.{1,80}(?:\s|$))/g
```

would suit your needs better.

Comment: thank you for your solution, it works perfectly. I am new to Perl and regex, could you please explain the regex you provided a little?

Comment: `(?: ...)` let's you use parentheses without creating a capture group. `\s` means any "space" (including tabs), and `$` is a special character that matches the end of the line. So `\s|$` means "match any space or the end of the line`

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand. Could you help to explain why it can make a line of sentence with limited length without truncating the word?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
(.{1,80}\b[^a-zA-Z0-9])
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/oQ3hX1

code:

```
print "$_\n" for grep substr($_, 0, 80), /(.{1,80}\b[^a-zA-Z0-9])/g;
```